# Special L for Lie Derivative

Tags: fonts, symbols, characters

Does anyone happen to know how to typeset the special L character found, for example, in eq. 2.41 in this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.5792v2.pdf that is being used for the Lie derivative?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems to be the pound symbol: try `\mathsterling`. By the way, there is a website which can help you with this type of questions: http://detexify.kirelabs.org. And [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Corentin Thanks for the tip and the welcome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sadly I think this is probably the sign for GBP (Great British Pounds) which is achieved with `\pounds`.

Comment: In fact you can go to http://arxiv.org/format/1107.5792 and download the TeX source file for their document. There you'll find the command \newcommand\Lie{\pounds}.

Comment: there's nothing sad about the Great British Pound! :)

Comment: Oh wow that's actually hilarious; I didn't notice that.  Thanks for the tip about TeX source also btw!

Comment: No, it's only sad to see it abused and out of context! ;)

No worries. It's something good to keep in mind for the next time you upload a paper to the arXiv!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the [pound sterling sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sign) (£)? You could just use the unicode character: `£`. I think it might even be on any keyboard with some Alt+key or Strg+key combination. On my mac it is Alt+Shift+4, just where the $ is.

Answer (score 2):

`\mathcal{L}` is what I have used in the past, if you don't want to use the `\pounds` sign.

Comment: Yeah I considered that but then realized that \mathcal is hella played out.

Comment: Heh, just realized that if you pronounce \mathcal{L} out loud, it sounds like a math-y Superman...

Answer (score 1):

`\usepackage{amssymb}` gives you a variety of stylized symbols such as `mathcal`, `mathfrak`, and so on. You can get the standard Lie derivative symbol (like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative)) with `\mathcal{L}`.

Comment: `\mathcal` doesn't need `amsmath`, it's part of the kernel.

Comment: its `amssymb` not `amsmath`

Comment: Ups, yes, sorry, I meant `amssymb`, but my comment stands: you don't need `amssymb` for `\mathcal`.

Comment: oh yeah, you are right. I just checked in overleaf and vs code without using any packages. Previously I answered based on [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_fonts)